# Forcing page breaks in proc report

Tags: pdf, sas

I'm creating a 2-column report in SAS using `PROC REPORT` inside the `ODS PDF` statement.

My code looks something like this:

```
ods pdf file='/file/here.pdf' columns=2;
ods pagestart=now;

proc report data=rpt\_data nowd missing contents='';
columns a b c;
by a;
define a /group order=internal;
define b /display;
define c /display;

break after a /page;
run;
```

This only seems to "break" to the next *column* on the page, rather than an actual *new page* like I would like it to.

Any suggestions?

**Running this code will produce the issue I'm inquiring about.**

```
%let file1='/file/directory/test.pdf';

ods pdf file=&file1. columns=2;
ods pdf startpage=now;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=temp;
by age;
run;
proc report data=temp nowd missing contents='';
columns age name sex;
by age;
define age /group order=internal;
define name /display;
define sex /display;

break after age /page;
run;
ods \_all\_ close;
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example using a data in the sashelp library (like sashelp.class)? It might help people to understand the problem more precisely.

Comment: Along with the above comment, maybe a sample of how it is breaking the page / columns you're referring to?

Comment: you might try playing around with setting ods escapechar='^';  Then add a compute block in proc report:  compute after _page_; line '^P'; endcomp; as that will force another page break in a pdf. My proc report-fu is weak so I wasn't ever satisfied with what I got but maybe you will have more success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not *yet* possible for the ods pdf destination as of 9.2. That is,  without very ugly hacks like adding ghost rows to the short by-group and coloring them with the background color so that they are invisible on paper, and so on. SAS's technical support is quite responsive. I would call/email them before I give up, though. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be practical in your case, but just in case: You can set page breaks if you use the [ODS "Measured RTF" destination](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsrtf/measured.html) ; then you could convert your RTF file to a pdf...

Comment: This might be useful, but from the little time I had to look at it, I decided that it would require too much work to accomplish. Thanks for the info though!